# What is the different between stack and call stack in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, stack, heap-memory, callstack

I'm now learning the basics of javascript. I face confusion about the difference between Stack and Call stack on the video and article I watch and read.

here is the stack I watch from the videos, and it said stack is a place to put your primitive values and pointer.

[image]

and in another article, I also got the term call stack, which is a data structure that stores information about the active subroutines of a computer program

[image]

are those terms the same or it has a subtle difference? or is it my mistake to understand them? thanks

Comment: I'd not recommend learning internal mechanism like this as first step to learn JavaScript, they are abstract enough and you usually need not worry about them.

Comment: Agree with @appleapple . There is enough information overload involved in learning the basic code writing and figuring out how to make your app do what you need it to. You can easily find yourself going down a lot of time wasting rabbit holes just to come out more confused than when you started when you realize you don't know enough of the basics to absorb the advanced topics. There are going to be many many things you will come across that you need to just store in the "I know it exists" drawer and come back to them on an as needed basis

Comment: when using recursion remember about proper **base case** so then the stack won't overflow

Answer (score 0):

Stack in `Stack & Heap` sense is where a program stores a method's variables values or references (reference values are stored in Heap).  For clarification I will call it `State` of method.

But an application running, typically has only one active `Stack`. so when you call another method (or itself recursively like your example) we need to save current `State` and create new space  to store `State` of newly called method so we can restore previous method's `State` afterward.
We do this with a data structure called `Stack` that support Last-In-First-Out (LIFO) to track called methods `State`. We call that `Call Stack`